# Are there any cons to using Joda-Time?

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to convince the architecture manager to include the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) jar in our product.

Do you know any disadvantages in using it?

I think Joda-Time needs to be constantly updated because of the files that it includes. And that is a disadvantage. Maybe I am wrong.

Could you provide some clarity on the subject?

Comment: FYI, the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, and advises migration to its successor, [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). The java.time classes are part of Java SE (Standard Edition), built into version 8 and later. Back-ports available for much of the functionality: [for Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp) and [for Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I've had almost entirely positive experiences with Joda Time. My one problem was when trying to construct my own time zone (for legitimate reasons, I assure you :) I got some very weird exceptions, and the documentation wasn't very good for that particular use case.

However, for the most part it's been a joy to use - immutability makes code a lot easier to reason about, and thread-safety for formatters is hugely useful.

Yes, there are files to keep up to date - but at least you *can* keep them up to date. It's not like they contain things which were unnecessary with Java's built-in stuff, it's just that with Java's mechanism you just couldn't keep information like timezones up to date without significant hackery!

Basically, +1 for using Joda Time. The Java date/time API is one of the worst bits of the Java platform, IMO.

Comment: Can someone provide details on Joda Time updates?  Specifically, I want to know if Joda Time forces you to keep the files up to date.  The business I work at is ultra-conservative on updating its libraries (it's like pulling teeth to get them to update, let alone request a new one) and I'd like to know how this works before I make the request.  For instance, if Joda Time just stops working if it doesn't find updated files, then it's too risky.

Answer (score 35):

In my opinion, the most important drawback in Joda-Time is about precision: many databases store timestamps with [microsecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) (or even [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond)) precision. Joda-time goes only to [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). This is not acceptable to me: all "data model" classes that I use need to reflect the full precision of the data in my database. Approximations or truncations of my data by a library just don't cut it.

Here is the reasoning behind the choice of millisecond precision, taken from the [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) mailing list:

> *"Joda-Time chose to use milliseconds as it made conversions to Date and Calendar easier."* - S. Colebourne

Easier for whom? The author of the library, one would assume... Incorrect design decision, in my opinion, when almost all databases store times to microsecond/nanosecond precision. The disregard for database values is worrying.

Comment: I can see microsecond or nanosecond precision being important if you are problem domain deals with sub-atomic particles.  And I can also understand that if your DB has micro/nano values, you don't want those truncated. But for 99% of the use cases out there, millisecond accuracy is quite sufficient.

Comment: Oracle, DB2, and PostgreSQL can all store timestamp values to microsecond or greater precision. Those are hardly obscure databases, now are they?

Comment: John O - I said nothing of the database being obscure. My point is that for most use cases, that kind of precision doesn't matter.  Just because your database CAN store that precision doesn't mean that you must.  Joda time is a good tool and not worth eliminating unless your use case requires higher precision dates. For these situations, simply store dates with only millisecond precision if you don't want approximations or truncations to occur. Of course, if your application requires micro or nano precision, then Joda time might not be the best tool for the job.

Comment: The successor to Joda-Time, [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), has [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution.

Answer (score 11):

The biggest issue that we had when using Joda Time was with integration with Spring and Tapestry, as they both wanted to use the built-in Date and Time.  We were constantly writing wrappers in getters/setters for date and time: either we would store it as Joda Time and one set of getters/setters passed it through and the other would convert on the fly, and some classes stored it internally as a Java Date/Time, and the Joda getter/setter had to switch it on the fly.

Basically, it was a headache because the classes are similarly named, and unless you can get your entire architecture (including other libraries you're integrating) to switch to Joda Time, you are going to write more wrapper code than you are likely to save by using the Joda libraries.

Comment: I don't know about Tapestry, but in Spring it's pretty easy to write your own converters, so certainly the Spring *config* file could easily handle Joda Time. Some of its own libraries might be more of a pain, admittedly.

Comment: As of Spring MVC v3, Joda Time classes are automagically supported in the [@DateTimeFormatter annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format-annotations-api) if you've got the Joda Time JAR in your classpath. I've been using it and haven't had to do _any_ wrapping or conversion in order to bind to forms etc (admittedly, my stack is Joda-all-the-way-down already)

Comment: The wonderful [Tapestry Jumpstart](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/home.html) covers the usage of Joda Time with Tapestry. [Here](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/jodatime/jodatime) and [here](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/lang/propertyeditors).

Answer (score 5):

Parleys hosts [a presentation by Stephen Colebourne about JSR-310](http://www.parleys.com/#st=5&id=100&sl=1), Mr. Colebourne the author of Joda-Time and JSR-310. He starts out by explaining the weaknesses of the standard date/time support in Java and why you'd want to use an alternative. It may be helpful to show this presentation to your architecture manager. I can't seem to deep-link

The reason Joda-Time updates its timezone file fairly often is because timezone data changes all the time, often on short notice (today on slashdot: [leap second added on 2008-12-31](http://news.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=08/12/29/0216214)) and not always scientifically motivated (e.g. I recall some pacific island state changed its time zone to be the first country to enter the year 2000).

Answer (score 2):

In the past, I've encountered companies that didn't want to incorporate third party open source software, or at least required the company lawyer to certify that the license wasn't going to expose them to any sort of liability or have a viral effect on their product.

As with any third party libraries, you should probably put it into source control so you can find the version that you shipped with particular releases of your code in case something goes wrong.

Comment: The successor to Joda-Time, [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), is indeed now part of Java SE (Standard Edition), built into version 8 and later. So no need to worry about third-party issues.

Answer (score 2):

The choice of milliseconds for the underlying time continuum is good for implementing calendars of antiquity, and special calendars.  Unlike many counters, the 64-bit millisecond counter has good range coverage for calendars of antiquity, with rollover properties in excess of +/- 260 million years.

It does not handle leap seconds.  This is a good thing.  A smooth transition is proposed by the atomic clock folks to allow systems that do not deploy leap seconds to incrementally adjust their clocks over 100 seconds to accommodate the leap second correction.

Maintenance of timezone tables will also be an issue.

The underlying continuum also allows an old French calendar and clock that divided a day into 10 intervals called metric time instead of 24 hours.  The classic Chinese calendar divides a day into 100 increments, each just over 14 minutes in length.  All of these calendars can be implemented and coordinated on the underlying millisecond time continuum.

Comment: FYI… the successor to Joda-Time, [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), has [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with it is vendor lockin at least until it becomes part of the standard.

For the most part I would use longs to store any business date information on a database. This gives me the flexibility to adjust the precision as I see fit. In most cases I just convert them to java.util.Date.

Time zones I would treat to be a presentation level issue than a data issue. This simplifies the database and increases portability since databases can represent temporals in different fashions.

The standard Calendar class provides me with some date manipulation functions which I convert to millisecond since epoch data.

As for nanosecond precision I would store that as an offset from 0 as a separate long column.

Comment: The successor to Joda-Time, [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), is indeed now part of Java SE (Standard Edition), built into version 8 and later. Back-ports available [for Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp) and [for Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).