# Convert date to different timezone

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, timezone

I am trying to obtain a simple conversion from one time zone into another using Java Date and Calendar. I am trying to run the following code

```
    Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
    Date date = instance.getTime();
    System.out.println(date);

    GregorianCalendar instance2 = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Athens"));
    instance2.setTime(instance.getTime());
    System.out.println(instance2.getTime());
```

but that still returns the same date, rather than +1 hour... The whole problem seems trivial but i cannot find any simple answer to this. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Would you like to use [Joda time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/375803/1037210)? It's my preference.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230126/how-to-handle-calendar-timezones-using-java). It could come in handy.

Comment: I found another thing on the web, which is probably the cleanest solution, to use a date time format to parse the date string and return the Date in the corresponding time zone

Comment: See https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-date-and-time-between-timezone/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When you print the date using `System.out.println(date); or System.out.println(instance2.getTime());`, the `Date`  returned by `instance2.getTime()` is `TimeZone independent` and always prints the date in local timezone.

Instead you may want to use `DateFormat/SimpleDateFormat`:

```
  DateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
  formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
  System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

  formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Athens"));
  System.out.println(formatter.format(instance2.getTime()))
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the local timezone and not EPOCH seconds (timezone-independant)? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()

Comment: @akaIDIOT the internal representation is since epoch, when the date is printed the the local timezone is used, a feature/bug of `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @Bober02: Did you find something better? If yes, please share.

Comment: Obviously, formatter.format(instance2.getTime()) changes the timeZone but when we convert this string date back to date object, it again picks up the local timezone. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @ParkashKumar: Date is timezone independent so you have two workarounds. 1. Adjust the offset to treat the local date with timezone dependent value. 2. Use Timezone dependent objects with right handling.

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer is correct. The java.util.Date class has no time zone assigned<sup>†</sup>, yet it's `toString` implementation confusingly applies the JVM's current default time zone.

## Avoid java.util.Date & .Calendar

This is one of many reasons to avoid the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date, .Calendar, and SimpleDateFormat classes bundled with Java. Avoid them. Instead use either:

- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- The new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) bundled with Java 8 and inspired by Joda-Time.

## Joda-Time

Some example code in Joda-Time 2.3 follows. Search StackOveflow for many more examples and much discussion.

```
DateTimeZone timeZoneLondon = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/London" );
DateTimeZone timeZoneAthens = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Athens" );

DateTime nowLondon = DateTime.now( timeZoneLondon );
DateTime nowAthens = nowLondon.withZone( timeZoneAthens );
DateTime nowUtc = nowLondon.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

## java.time

Java 8 and later has a new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built-in. This package was inspired by Joda-Time. While they share some similarities and class names, they are different; each has features the other lacks. One notable difference is that java.time avoids constructors, instead uses static instantiation methods.

In the case of this Question, they work in the same fashion. Specify a time zone, and call a [`now`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) method to get current moment, then create a new instance based on the old immutable instance to adjust for time zone.

Note the two different time zone classes. One is a named time zone including all the rules for Daylight Saving Time and other such anomalies plus an offset from UTC while the other is only the offset.

```
ZoneId zoneMontréal = ZoneId.of("America/Montreal"); 
ZonedDateTime nowMontréal = ZonedDateTime.now ( zoneMontréal );

ZoneId zoneTokyo = ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo"); 
ZonedDateTime nowTokyo = nowMontréal.withZoneSameInstant( zoneTokyo );

ZonedDateTime nowUtc = nowMontréal.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

---

<sup>†</sup>Actually the `java.util.Date` class *does* have a time zone buried within [its source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Date.java). But the class ignores that time zone for most practical purposes. So, as shorthand, it’s often said that j.u.Date has no time zone assigned. Confusing? Yes. Avoid the mess that is j.u.Date and go with Joda-Time and/or java.time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code snippet

```
String dateString = "14 Jul 2014 00:11:04 CEST";
date = formatter.parse(dateString);
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

// Set the formatter to use a different timezone - Indochina Time
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Bangkok"));
System.out.println("ICT time : "+formatter.format(date));
```