# How to get time according to timezone

Tags: java

I am storing timezone value in database as `+5:30` or `+2:00` or `-1:00`

I am fetching data from database and changing time according to time zone in java.

Here I would like to know how can I get time according to saved timezone value.

Comment: Possible answer present at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429357/date-and-time-conversion-to-some-other-timezone-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Use `Timezone` and `Calendar`. And check SO before asking...

Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230126/how-to-handle-calendar-timezones-using-java), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197956/convert-date-to-different-timezone?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeZone tz = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone();
System.out.println(tz.getDisplayName());// (i.e. Moscow Standard Time)
System.out.println(tz.getID());
```

That should get the time zone that the computer the user is using has been set to.

Unless you want to use a complicated solution by pinging a server and making a server-side check to see where the IP came from, then that is the closest you're going to get.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` and `setTimeZone`

```
String timeZone = "GMT" + offset // offset is the value you store in the db( +5:30, -2:30)

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
Date date = format.parse("2014-11-19T09:01:02");
```